# access data on apache server using xampp

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, xampp

i am writing an iphone application, which basically uploads and downloads Images to/from a server. in order to test my code i installed xampp and everything works fine now. if i upload an image the server creates a folder named with the UDID-number of the device
(via the http-method POST a php script is called).

but if i enter the directory of such a folder and the name of the image in the browser i can see it in the browser.
i am a newby on this topic and have no idea if there are better possibilities. my questions are: should i use databases where i save the images or is it just fine to create folders via a php script and save the images into these folders? can i hide all the datastructure, such that you cannot access it via a browser but only with the iphone application? (the application should only be able to download pictures randomly). thx

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want an image serverable by apache, you need to store it outside the webroot.  So if your webroot is C:\xampp\htdocs, you could store the images in a folder structure under C:\xampp\images

Your iphone app would have to do a little more work then to pull a random one and send it to the user.

Comment: well... how can i download an image then when i can´t access the directory? is it possible to call a php script on the server, which has access to the structure C:/xampp/images? and how can a php script pass an image back to the iphone then?! well.. questions over questions... plz help :)

Comment: Sorry about the delay. It is possible to have PHP access the files as long as it has permissions to do so. Look into file_get_contents(). You can give it a local path and it will return the contents of the image. You could then create a temp file, or stream it somewhere else.  There's probably something out there that would let you stream a file directly to the user as a download too.